# How to add a global oncomplete JavaScript method to Richfaces?

Tags: javascript, jquery, richfaces

I'm looking for a possibility to attach a JavaScript method which is always invoked after every AJAX request?

In detail: I would like to listen to changes on the columns (using paginator, sorting, filter) and invoke a method after the Richfaces implementation was called.

Since Richfaces 4.x is based on jQuery, I guess there is a way to do this with jQuery?

Comment: Show us some of your code, what you've tried so far and what errors you're getting. As it now stands, you're not giving enough info to go on

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have overseen the `onready` attribute of the Extended Data Table.

```
<rich:extendedDataTable onready="foo();" ...
```

`foo()` will be invoked after every change on the Extended Data Table.

Answer (score 1):

You could use [`a4j:status`](http://livedemo.exadel.com/richfaces-demo/richfaces/status.jsf).

Example:

```
<a4j:status id="generalStatus" onstop="javascript:callJsMethod();" />
```

Comment: Thank you. I'm not using `<a4j:status`, this didn't work good enough for me since it broke my CSS using `<a4j:region`. However, you're hint has led to the solution!

Answer (score 1):

You could also use [jsf.ajax](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17802_01/j2ee/javaee/javaserverfaces/2.0/docs/js-api/symbols/jsf.ajax.html).

Here is a example that will be invoked after every ajax-request:

```
jsf.ajax.addOnEvent(function(data) {
  console.log(data.status);

  // data.status have 3 values (begin, complete, success)
  if (data.status === 'success') {
    // do stuff
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code that will call your code whenever `xhr.send();` is executed.

```
XMLHttpRequest.prototype.send = function(){
var b = XMLHttpRequest.prototype.send;
    return function () { 
        console.log('calllllled'); // your code goes here.
        b.apply(this,arguments);        
    }
}();
```

Thanks to information provided this is all i can do :D

Comment: Thank you but your solution did not work for me. `calllllled` was printed before the AJAX request was done.